# How to detect if Angular ng-repeat is showing result or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to show "No result" message when I type something into the search field and there is no match.
Currently the filter works but when I type a keyword that doesn't give a result it doesn't show a 
"no result" message. How to do that?

```
<div class="portfolio-list-wrap" ng-controller="LatestProjectCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$"/>
<div class="portfolio-thumb" ng-repeat="work in works.project | filter:search">
    <img src="images/{{work.string}}.jpg" alt="{{work.name}}"/>
    <h4>{{work.name}}</h4>
    <i>{{work.date}}</i>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is how I did my factory

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Works', function(){

var Works = {}

Works.project =[
    {
        name : "project1",
        string : "projectstring1",
        date: "17 August 2012"
    },
    {
        name : "project2",
        string : "projectstring2",
        date: "12 December 2013"
    },
    {
        name : "project3",
        string : "projectstring3",
        date: "17 September 2012"
    },
    {
        name : "project3",
        string : "projectstring4",
        date: "17 August 2012"
    },
];  
return Works;
})



function LatestProjectCtrl($scope, Works){
$scope.works = Works;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can show a message saying that there is no results like this:

```
<span ng-show="(projects | filter:query).length == 0">No results</span>
```

For complete example please see the code snippet below:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.projects = [
      {
        name: "Sunny project 1",
        date: "17.3.2016",
        image: "pr1"
      },
      {
        name: "Windy project 2",
        date: "18.03.2016",
        image: "pr2"
      },
      {
        name: "Cloudy project 3",
        date: "19.03.2016",
        image: "pr3"
      }
    ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="query" />
    <div class="portfolio-thumb" ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:query">
      <h4>{{project.name}}</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>{{project.date}}</li>
        <li>Img source = '{{project.image}}.jpg'</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="(projects | filter:query).length == 0">No results</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-show="(works | filter:search).length == 0"` is correct? have you check it?

Comment: and OP have bind `works.project`  values not a `works`

Comment: He posted a fiddle, do you think your question is relevant?

Comment: By the way your answer is very useful I just did <span ng-show="(works.project | filter:search).length == 0">no result</span> and it works for me thank you PrimosK.

Comment: Doesn't the filter logic get called twice in this solution? It might become sluggish if the filter is complex with large amount of data.

Comment: The JSFiddle is not work anymore. Error 404 says it quite well.

Comment: @UlrikH.Kold, thanks for pointing this out. I've replaced missing JSFiddle with the Code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
<div class="portfolio-thumb" ng-repeat="work in filteredList = (works.project | filter:search)">
    <img src="images/{{work.string}}.jpg" alt="{{work.name}}"/>
    <h4>{{work.name}}</h4>
    <i>{{work.date}}</i>

</div>
<span ng-hide="filteredList.length"> No result</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkPtL/3/)

**Update:**

Even more elegant is to use

```
 <span ng-hide="filteredList"> No result</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkPtL/1/)

Comment: if the filteredList.length is return  0 or 1, then how can you set true or false for ng-hide option? bcs ng-hide only get true or false value

Comment: yes, But  have you 100% sure  in angularjs? for show hide properties?

Comment: oh ! nope,what you think, ng-hide is a property or statement?   Am 100% sure it's not possible. I already get a stuff in this same task, ng-hide is a property, not a statement. So  The javascript statement only can get values undefined or 0 to false.Not property get this \

Comment: and also your code have nothing relation `filteredList `

Comment: Nope, buddy, you have missed that. See your code is not working in fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/tRxzr/263/

Comment: I also think, you have core of JS Knowledge

Answer (score -2):

You need show and hide option for error message

```
<div class="portfolio-list-wrap" ng-controller="LatestProjectCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$"/>
<h2 ng-if="works.project===undefined || works.project.length===0">You have no results</h2>
<div ng-if="works.project!==undefined || works.project.length!==0" >
<div class="portfolio-thumb" ng-repeat="work in works.project | filter:search">
    <img src="images/{{work.string}}.jpg" alt="{{work.name}}"/>
    <h4>{{work.name}}</h4>
    <i>{{work.date}}</i>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
```

See your works.project is undefined, then shown a error message, else the div shown .

Please see this conditions

```
<h2 ng-if="works.project===undefined || works.project.length===0">You have no results</h2>
    <div ng-if="works.project!==undefined || works.project.length!==0" >...
```